# Latest and better way to assert method call parameters in Mockito java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, assertions

Right now to test my mock service method call parameters i use below techniques, is there any better or latest way to do that?

```
@Test
public void testSendOutBidNotificationWhenCurrentBidderIsNotNullAndDifferentThenUserWithBidDifferenceNonZero(){ 
    Event event = new Event();
    event.setCurrency(Currency.USD);
    Item item = new Item();
    item.setCode("TST");
    User user = new User("current@current.com", 8888888888L);

    User currentHighBidder = new User("high@high.com", 9999999999L);
    item.setCurrentHighBidder(currentHighBidder);

    doReturn(10).when(itemService).getBidIncrement(any(), any());

    ArgumentCaptor<TextMessage> textMessageCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(TextMessage.class);
    textMessagePrepareService.sendOutBidNotification(event, item, user, 20, currentHighBidder);

    verify(textMessageService).sendText(textMessageCaptor.capture());
    assertEquals("You have been outbid for item TST. The new bid is $20, so you need to bid $10 more than that to win the item. For example: TST$30", 
                    textMessageCaptor.getValue().getMessage());

}
```

here i am capturing the TextMessage which will be used as parameter in sendText method and testing the values in that which will be constructed previously.

Method under test is as Below

```
public void sendOutBidNotification(Event event, Item item, User user, int bidAmount, User currentHighBidder){
    if (currentHighBidder != null && !currentHighBidder.equals(user)) {
        log.info("Outbid person different: " + currentHighBidder);
        try {
            int bidIncrement = itemService.getBidIncrement(item, eventService.getAuction(event));

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("increment", String.valueOf(bidIncrement));
            params.put("required", String.valueOf(bidAmount + bidIncrement));
            params.put("amount", String.valueOf(bidAmount));
            params.put("item_code", item.getCode());
            params.put("currency_symbol", event.getCurrency().getSymbol());

            String loserMessage = this.getLooserOutBidNotificationMessage(bidIncrement, params); 

            TextMessage textMessage = new TextMessage(loserMessage, event.getAePhoneNumber(), currentHighBidder, loserMessage);
            textMessageService.sendText(textMessage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception Occurred : " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you're doing is perfectly fine.  If you wanted to avoid using an `ArgumentCaptor`, you could write a `Matcher` that calls `getMessage` on its argument, but there's really no point.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way: don't use `new` to create that TextMessage. Instead, have a **factory** that creates the message for you; and use dependency injection go put that factory in your class under test.

Because then you gain **control** over that TextMessage object that gets used when that method is called! Meaning: you could mock that factory, and have it return a "known" TextMessage object. And now you only need to verify that your service is called with **that** object. That allows you to just do a simply argument match; and you can get rid of that ArgumentCaptor and the assert on it completely!

And that would be really good; as: doing an assertEquals() for the **text** of a message is bad practice. Those messages change all the time; and people will get annoyed quickly when they find that changing the content of some resource bundle that contains the message text breaks a unit test.

Comment: ok instead i moved my message generator to another utility base component which give me loserMessage so now i can test that logic inside that class and mock it for this class, because my base motive was to test loser message.

Comment: If your comment is supposed to say: "your answer helped", then feel free to accept my answer then ;-)